# Resizing body height to fit screen, even if content is shorter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Not really sure how to go about this. Basically, my page has a header, nav, body and footer contained in a wrapper, all of which is contained within the body (of course). The wrapper is set to fill 60% of the screen and be centered. The header, nav and footer will always be the same height and simply fill the wrapper, width-wise.

The main section, however, has variable length content (paragraphs, images, articles, sections, etc). If I have a lot of content in the main section, the page fills up, stretches out and scrolls like normal. But if I have just a little bit of content in main, the page isn't long enough and the footer ends up about halfway up the screen (or however high it needs to be to follow after the tiny main).

What I want to do is ensure that the body and/or wrapper stretch to fill the height of the screen, even if the main section isn't necessarily long enough to force it to be that tall. I have tried making the body and wrapper `height: 100%` but the wrapper is still not extending. If I set the footer to `position: fixed`, the footer sizing freaks out and the wrapper borders do not extend down.

Given these problems, I think the best solution would be somehow increasing the main section's height so that it and the other elements always add up to a minimum of 100%, but I can't figure out how to do this.  This has stumped me for a week, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle demonstrating your problem?

Comment: You can set a min-height to the content in CSS

Comment: Timmerz, here's a JSFiddle link for you: http://jsfiddle.net/378feuLu/

Anpsmn, setting a min-height in the main section doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may work.  It just styles both your body tag, your wrapper, and your HTML to fill the height of it's container.

```
html, body, #wrapper {
   height: 100%;
}
```

I don't think I can be more specific than that without a simplified version of your HTML / CSS.

--edit--

I forked your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4p3oL86z/) with a working example.  All I did was add the above snippet into the CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the height to 100% doesn't make the div stretch beyond the height of the content. It makes html and body extend to match the screen height, but not the div or its contents.

See this JSFiddle for some more info: http://jsfiddle.net/378feuLu/

Comment: I added an example using my snippet with your code.  It works :)

Answer (score 0):

As Eclecticist already stated. You need to set your html and body to 100% height. That is necessary because the wrapper-element inherits the height of the parent. Therefor setting the wrapper to 100%-height will never get it bigger that it's parent.
In addition to Eclecticists answer I would recommend you to set the wrappers **min-height** to 100% so the content won't run out of the container as soon as it exceeds the window height:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```